# MYSQL SELECT. How to distinguish customers by first four digits of number field

Tags: mysql

I have a table (billing) with the following structure

```
msisdn bigint 20
result varchar 10
event_time datetime
bill_type tinyint 4
```

I need to locate records for customers with specific prefixes in the msisdn field.

For example

```
SELECT msisdn,bill_type,event_time from billing
where result = 00
and msisdn LIKE '2782%'
or msisdn LIKE '2772%'
or msisdn LIKE '2778%'
```

However all data is being returned. I think due to the OR command.

What would be the best way to get the data I want only for msisdn's that match particular prefixes, such as 2782,2772, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try putting the `OR`s in parens:

```
SELECT msisdn,bill_type,event_time from billing
where result = 00
and (msisdn LIKE '2782%'
or msisdn LIKE '2772%'
or msisdn LIKE '2778%')
```